# Print Rails User Model Validate Method To View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have a user model that can select different enums (Options for displaying their contact info):

```
enum email_option: [ :email_always, :email_normal, :email_never ]
enum phone_option: [ :phone_always, :phone_normal, :phone_never ] 


validate :settings_allowed

def settings_allowed
  if email_never? && phone_never?
    puts "Working"
    errors.add(:user, "Can't do this" )
  end
end
```

Everything works fine in the background.
The Error is called in the Console, **however** I don't know how to print this error message in my view.

Thanks!

Comment: I believe you need to `return false`